# Expo Couldn't start project on Android: could not connect to TCP port 5554: Connection refused

Tags: android, react-native, expo, adb

I am using mac and Expo 4.4.4.
When I am trying to run Expo on Android Emulator Getting below error :

```
Couldn't start project on Android: could not connect to TCP port 5554: Connection refused
```

I tried the below cmds in the terminal to get rid of offline device

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
emulator-5556   device

$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
emulator-5556   device

$ lsof -i :5555
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
adb     13691 sujayun    9u  IPv4 0xd716e907b32c7e05      0t0  TCP localhost:54347->localhost:personal-agent (ESTABLISHED)
$ kill -9 13691

$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
emulator-5556   device
```

What ever I try, I am not able to rid of offline device.

Is there any way to remove this ? or start expo on TCP 5556 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After battling for 3 days found the issue and solved it.

I checked with all processes listening on different ports

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN
launchd      1           root   11u  IPv6 0x19938282208649b9      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
kdc        196           root    5u  IPv6 0x1993828220866e79      0t0    TCP *:88 (LISTEN)
wftpserve  383           root    7u  IPv6 0x1993828220864399      0t0    TCP *:5555 (LISTEN)
wftpserve  383           root    8u  IPv4 0x199382822086dee9      0t0    TCP *:5555 (LISTEN)
mDNSRespo  285 _mdnsresponder   82u  IPv4 0x19938282276928c9      0t0    TCP *:53 (LISTEN)
MEGAclien  546          root    32u  IPv4 0x1993828225a7e8c9      0t0    TCP localhost:6341 (LISTEN)
adb       1064          root    12u  IPv4 0x19938282279288c9      0t0    TCP localhost:5037 (LISTEN)
```

Check with the service whose TCP is listening on 5554 + 1 = 5555

This service might be causing the automatic start of the offline emulator

Kill that process with PID, 
In my case it was wftpserve service with PID 383

```
$ sudo kill -9 383
```

Then the emulator disappeared

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

Then Expo started on my Android emulator

Comment: I faced the same issue and killing my 5555 process fixed it

Comment: Oh man it was the docker... Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Open your prompt command and type this

1-first

```
$ adb devices
```

2-second

```
$ adb kill-server
```

3-and next

```
$ adb start-server
```

Comment: Easy peasy lemon squeezy! Thanks! :)

Comment: This worked for me. @joao Could you explain what was the problem?

Comment: I could't start the emulator Android and IOS on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue: Error: could not connect to TCP port 5554: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5554: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

Followed @sujay U N's answer on Windows.

Just had to list devices using

```
adb devices
```

Then delete the process that ran on port 5554